# DOM añadir items a option tecleando

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, dom, function

Sobre los items existentes, ¿de qué manera podría añadir alguno nuevo (valor nuevo, contenido nuevo y posición) introduciendo datos en estos campos y al hacer click sobre "nuevo item"? Solo he conseguido añadirlos al option "manualmente", pero no de esta forma que se me pide (la función es la última, newItem())

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/*****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS DOM - Eliminar elementos del DOM</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <select id="colorSelect">
    <option value=”1”>Uno</option>
    <option value=”2”>Dos</option>
    <option value=”3”>Tres</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:delItemSelected()">Elimina el item seleccionado</a>
    <a href="javascript:delAllItems()">Vacía el desplegable</a>
    <a href="javascript:resetItems()">Reset desplegable</a>
    <hr>
    Valor: <input type="text" name="valor_nuevo" value="">
    Contenido: <input type="text" name="contenido_nuevo" value="">
    Posición: <input type="text" name="posicion" value="">
    <a href="javascript:newItem()">Nuevo item</a>
    </form>

    <script>

    function delItemSelected(){
        var seleccionado=document.getElementById("colorSelect");
        seleccionado.remove(seleccionado.selectedIndex);
    }

    function delAllItems(){
        var borrarTodos=document.getElementById("colorSelect");
        var elementos=3;
        for(var i=0;i<elementos;i++){
            borrarTodos.remove(elementos.selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    function resetItems(){
        var borrarTodos=document.getElementById("colorSelect");
        var elementos=3;
        for(var i=0;i<elementos;i++){
            borrarTodos.remove(borrarTodos.selectedIndex);
        }

        var arrayVacio=[];

        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            arrayVacio[i]=document.createElement("option");
        }

        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            switch(i){
                case 0: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML="Uno";
                break;
                case 1: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML="Dos";
                break;
                case 2: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML="Tres";
                break;
            }
            borrarTodos.appendChild(arrayVacio[i]);
        }
    }

    function newItem(){
        var nuevo=document.createElement("option");
var option=document.createTextNode("Cuatro");
    /*var option=document.getElementsByName("contenido_nuevo")[0].value;
    document.getElementById("colorSelect").innerHTML=option;*/
    nuevo.appendChild(option);
    document.getElementById("colorSelect").appendChild(nuevo);

    }


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la tónica de programa, necesitas manipular el DOM directamente y crear nodos.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <select id="colorSelect">
            <option value=”1”>Uno</option>
            <option value=”2”>Dos</option>
            <option value=”3”>Tres</option>
        </select>
        <a href="javascript:delItemSelected()">Elimina el item seleccionado</a>
        <a href="javascript:delAllItems()">Vacía el desplegable</a>
        <a href="javascript:resetItems()">Reset desplegable</a>
        <hr>
        Valor: <input type="text" name="valor_nuevo" value="">
        Contenido: <input type="text" name="contenido_nuevo" value="">
        Posición: <input type="text" name="posicion" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Añadir elemento">
    </form>
    <script>

        function delItemSelected() {
            var seleccionado = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
            seleccionado.remove(seleccionado.selectedIndex);
        }

        function delAllItems() {
            var borrarTodos = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
            var elementos = 3;
            for (var i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
                borrarTodos.remove(elementos.selectedIndex);
            }
        }

        function resetItems() {
            var borrarTodos = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
            var elementos = 3;
            for (var i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
                borrarTodos.remove(borrarTodos.selectedIndex);
            }

            var arrayVacio = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                arrayVacio[i] = document.createElement("option");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML = "Uno";
                        break;
                    case 1: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML = "Dos";
                        break;
                    case 2: arrayVacio[i].innerHTML = "Tres";
                        break;
                }
                borrarTodos.appendChild(arrayVacio[i]);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            const select = this.colorSelect

            const value = this.valor_nuevo.value
            const content = this.contenido_nuevo.value
            const position = this.posicion.value

            const el = createNodeOption(value, content)
            select.insertBefore(el, select.childNodes[position]); 
        })

        function createNodeOption(value, content) {
            const el = document.createElement('option')
            el.setAttribute('value', value)
            el.text = content
            return el
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```